# Finding the maximum value in a specific axis of a 3D array for each group of values on the axis

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3D numpy array of shape (8, x, y) where x and y can be any integer value from 0 to ~500. These 8 "layers" of shape (x, y) each represent a possible z value at a specific point on a plane (the corresponding coordinates are stored separately). **The z values can be positive or negative**.

How do I find the **signed** absolute maximum value at each coordinate point? Preferably without looping - these layers can get rather large.

*Simple example:*

```py
>>> a = np.array([
    [
      [3, 5],
      [-4, 1],
    ],
    [
      [1, 2],
      [1, 4],
    ],
    [
      [2, -3],
      [0, -5],
    ],
    [
      [-6, 4],
      [2, 2],
    ]
])
```

*Expected result:*

```py
[[-6, 5],
 [-4, -5]]
```

This is my current working example:

```py
a = np.array([
    [
        [3, 5],
        [-4, 1],
    ],
    [
        [1, 2],
        [1, 4],
    ],
    [
        [2, -3],
        [0, -5],
    ],
    [
        [-6, 4],
        [2, 2],
    ],
])

a_max = np.max(a, axis=0)
a_min = np.min(a, axis=0)

# Stack max and min for later masking via argmax
a_max_min = np.dstack([a_max, a_min])

# find max and min value indices
a_max_min_argmax = np.argmax(a_max_min, axis=0)
a_max_min_argmin = np.argmin(a_max_min, axis=0)

# Find absolute max array using mask
a_abs_max = a_max * a_max_min_argmax + a_min * a_max_min_argmin
```

Result:

```py
[[-6  5]
 [-4 -5]]
```

This works, but it is very rough. I also know that it will break if there is e.g. a -5 and a 5 at the same point.

How can I improve this? I think there should be a way to use `np.argmax(np.abs(a_max_min), axis=0)`, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you were definitely right about the argmax method.
Your code was very close

here is the final code:

```py
indices = np.argmax(np.abs(a), axis=0)
max_z = np.take_along_axis(a, indices[np.newaxis, ...], axis=0)

print(indices)
print(max_z)
```

argmax returns the indices where the maximum is located. And take_along_axis just loops through and grabs the numbers it needs based on the indices.

If you print it, you can see how it works, (for example, instead of showing -6 in the top left corner of indices, it shows 3. As -6 the number we want, is located in the 3rd 2D array).

To be honest though, I'm not certain if avoiding for loops is the right way for these things? I feel like Python is efficient enough with that stuff, unless if we're talking about some billion data points.

It should actually be noted about methods like the numpy ones, numpy is only more efficient because it implements its functions in C.

But however, if we start using numpy functions which loop over multiple times (for example, my solution loops over 1 more time than it needs to). It can eventually lead to worse performance than doing a basic for loop in Python (which python tries to optimize so much in the background for us anyway).

But learning to do it with numpy functions is cool too still.

Comment: Hi Minko_Minkov, thanks for the help! Your solution makes sense to me - I haven't used np.newaxis much. I appreciate the comment about looping vs not looping - I agree that in this case it might not be worth the effort. I was sure there had to be a way to do it in numpy, so thanks for the tip!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad if it helps in the end.

Answer (score 0):

mine looks kinda stupid but it works :)

```
absoluteNumber = np.max(np.abs(a), axis=0)
positive = np.abs(np.min(a, axis=0)) <= np.max(a, axis=0)
negative = np.abs(np.min(a, axis=0)) > np.max(a, axis=0)
result = absoluteNumber*positive -  absoluteNumber*negative 
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Potato! Wouldn't this also break in the same way as mine if there is a -5 and a 5 on the same axis?

Comment: You're welcome! No, it won't. In that case it will choose the positive number always.